summation of series (might include binomial)
For $a>0$ and $b>a+1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a(a+1)...(a+n-1)}{b(b+1)...(b+n-1)}$.
I've tried writing the numerator and denominator in terms of factorial then multiplied and divided by n! to convert it into $\binom{n}{r}$ form with n varying and then I was stuck and don't know how to proceed with two binomial coefficients summation in division.
Here I m attaching what i did in the question so far 

Does this restriction on $a$ and $b$ ensure that this sum converges ?

Write the summand in terms of factorials or gamma functions and add it in the post. The final result is simple.

@Sam I don't get any idea about it.

@ClaudeLeibovici I attached that now.

The image contains the correct conditions. For $b=a$ the sum doesn't converge, therefore $b<a+1$ is not possible. @Loopingoutlaw

@Sam but the condition given is b>a+1

@Sam oh sorry my bad i checked it now the condition is b>a+1

Let us prove by induction that
$$
S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{a(a+1)\dots(a+n-1)}{b(b+1)\dots(b+n-1)}=\frac{(a+N)!(b-1)!-(b+N-1)!a!}{(a-b+1)(b+N-1)!(a-1)!}
$$
Indeed, for $N=1$ this is true, $S_1=\frac{a}{b}$. Now, if this is true for $N$, then for $N+1$ we have
\begin{align*}
S_{N+1}&=\frac{(a+N)!(b-1)!-(b+N-1)!a!}{(a-b+1)(b+N-1)!(a-1)!}
+\frac{a(a+1)\dots(a+N)}{b(b+1)\dots(b+N)} 
\\ & =
\frac{(a+N)!(b-1)!-(b+N-1)!a!}{(a-b+1)(b+N-1)!(a-1)!}
+\frac{(a+N)!(b-1)!}{(a-1)!(b+N)!}
\\ & =
\frac{(a+N)!(b-1)!(b+N)-(b+N)!a!
+(a-b+1)(a+N)!(b-1)!}{(a-b+1)(a-1)!(b+N)!}
\\ & =
\frac{(a+N)!(b-1)![(b+N)+(a-b+1)]-(b+N)!a!}{(a-b+1)(a-1)!(b+N)!}
\\ & =
\frac{(a+N+1)!(b-1)!-(b+N)!a!}{(a-b+1)(a-1)!(b+N)!}=S_{N+1}.
\end{align*}
Now, since
$$
S_N=\frac{a}{b-1-a}\left[1-\frac{(b-1)!}{a!}\frac{(a+N)!}{(b-1+N)!}\right]
$$
assuming $b-1>a$ we get that $\lim_{N\to\infty} S_N=\frac{a}{b-1-a}.$

how did you get the first step of Sn =(a+N)!(b−1)!−(b+N−1)!a!(a−b+1)(b+N−1)!(a−1)!

How did I guess it? I computed a few first sums and then assumed the induction (so the proof goes by induction).
